# Bare minimum package.json

Tags: npm, package.json

When I run `npm init -y` I get the following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This however, includes several things that doesn't actually seem to be required.

1. What is actually the bare minimum `package.json`?
2. And, what I *really* want to know, is there a command or flag I can use to have *that* generated instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) states that the only required fields are `name` and `version`.

> **Required name and version fields**
>
> A **package.json** file must contain "**name**" and "**version**" fields:
>
> The "**name**" field contains your package’s name, and must be lowercase and one word, and may contain hyphens and underscores.
>
> The "**version**" field must be in the form **x.x.x** and follow the [semantic versioning guidelines](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) for `init`, there seems to be no way to initialize a package with only these fields though, looks like you would need to do this yourself (or create a bash script that can generate it for you).

You could create a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "{\n\t\"name\": \"$1\",\n\t\"version\": \"$2\"\n}" > package.json
```

And call it like this:

```
./init.sh test 1.0.0
```

Which would generate a file looking like this:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

If you want a script that replicated the behaviour of `npm init -y` (using the directory name and setting the version to 1.0.0), try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT=`pwd`
BASENAME=`basename "$CURRENT"`

printf "{\n\t\"name\": \"$BASENAME\",\n\t\"version\": \"1.0.0\"\n}" > package.json
```

Comment: I added an example bash script to create this basic package file from given input arguments.

Comment: Just the kind of answer I was looking for, and which will hopefully come up on google the next time I forget.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, as I found it interesting I couldn't help myself and added another example script replicating the behaviour of `npm init -y`

Answer (score 4):

`{"private": "true"}`

Is an effective solution if you never intend to publish the project. This keyword will stop the warnings and errors for all those irrelevant fields